# XCode: custom font is not applied

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts

I'm trying to add the custom font to my application. I've already tried to follow all standard recommendations from the documentation and the rest of articles related to the problem.

What I've done:

- [installed the font to the Font Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeT8w.png)
- [copied ttf files to application directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgB1K.png)
- [added font files to the "Fonts provided by application" in Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJQFA.png)
- checked app in "Target Membership"
- [checked font files in "Copy Bundle Resources"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aETWO.png)

As a result font is visible [in Attribute Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZThRd.png) and successfully changed in the LaunchScreen storyboard. But when I run app in simulator only size and colour are applied but not font-face.

I'm using XCode 12.2 (12B45b) in Big Sur.

What else should I try? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that the problem is only for `LaunchScreen`, you can't use custom fonts on the `LaunchScreen`. System will automatically replace your custom font to system font during runtime.

A quick workaround is to use an `UIImageView` and have your text as `UIImage` on it, literally a picture of your text as `.png` / `.jpeg` or similar.

**Note**: It may take some time before you can see the image, sometimes you had to clean the Build Folder and reinstall the app a couple of times in order to see the image.

Comment: I didn't associate this problem with LaunchScreen. Thank you, Omid.